# Vector spaces and infinite cyclic linear transformations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

Let $G$ be a direct sum of infinitey many copies of the group of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $G$ with infinite order.

> Is always possible to find an $\alpha$-invariant *subgroup* $M$ of $G$ such that $G/M$ is an Abelian torsion group with infinitely many primary components?

In the finite dimensional case I think this is pretty easy, but I can't work out the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by $V/M$ being periodic?  As a module over $\Bbb{Q}[t]$, where the action of $t$ descends from the action of $\alpha$ on $V$?

Comment: I mean periodic as an Abelian group.

Comment: As in these equivalent definitions?  (I've somehow never heard *periodic* used this way; *torsion* would be my choice.)  http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Periodic_abelian_group#Definition

Comment: Yes! Usually I indifferently use those two terms as synonymous.

Comment: I am confused. $V/M$ is a vector space over ${\mathbb Q}$, so how can it be periodic?

Comment: @DerekHolt you're right I expressed it in an unpleasant way. I meant that I'm looking for a subgroup $M$ of $(V,\, +)$ not for a subspace of $V$, as vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Finding subgroups of $G$ cannot change properties of $G$ (such as if $G$ is torsion or not). And if you meant to ask about $M$ instead of $G$, no nontrivial subgroup of a torsion-free group can be torsion.

Comment: Editing I forgot a $/M$... I meant $G/M$.